# how to handle twitter bootstrap button loading and reset in an emberjs view

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm trying to understand if this is the best way to do things here, because to me it looks like a code smell.
What I want to do is that my button changes to the loading state when I click it, and it changes back to the default state when the controller ends handling the event (basically makes and AJAX call)

My template looks like this:

```
{{#view App.LoadingButton action="search" data-loading-text="content.loadingText"}}Search{{/view}}
```

My view looks like this:

```
App.LoadingButton = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    classNames: ['btn', 'btn-primary'],
    attributeBindings: ['type'],
    type: 'button',
    elem: null,
    stateChanged: function () {
        if (this.elem) {
            var loading = this.get('controller').get('content.isLoading');
            if (loading) {
                $(this.elem).button('loading');
            }
            else {
                $(this.elem).button('reset');
            }            
        }        
    },
    click: function (evt) {
        this.elem = this.elem || evt.srcElement;
        this.get('controller').send(this.get('action'));
    },
    didInsertElement: function () {
        this.get('controller').addObserver('content.isLoading', this, 'stateChanged');
    }
});
```

1. First, the way I'm accessing my element looks just wrong, can't I
   get a ref to my view's element when it's being added to the DOM?
2. Second, I'm relying on the controller to change the isLoading boolean flag from its model, so that the view knows when to change states, is this the best way to implement it in the Ember way ?

I've seen a lot of videos of Ember, just starting implementing with it, and it's still not straightforward to know what's the best approach, even though it might work, like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I want to do is that my button changes to the loading state when I click it, and it changes back to the default state when the controller ends handling the event (basically makes and AJAX call).

You're describing the document/event-focused architecture (with tight display/interaction coupling) that Ember helps people move away from. Ember is about more about describing the data state of your application and how the display appears in each state. Ember itself will handle the synchronization of data to display for you.

A more Ember-like way to describe this would be:

- Display behavior

  - When I am communicating with the server the button has a `disabled` class and displays "Loading..."
  - When I am not communicating with the sever the button does not have a `disabled` class as displays "Search"
  - When interacted with, this button will  trigger the search action

Template:

```
<button type="button" 
        {{bindAttr class=":btn :btn-primary isLoading:disabled"}} 
        {{action search}}>
  {{#if isLoading}}
    Loading...
  {{else}}
    Search
  {{/if}}
</button>
```

- Flow control behavior

  - When search is triggered, the controller's `isLoading` becomes true
  - When search completes, the controller's `isLoading` property becomes false
  - If search is already in progress, ignore attempts to search again

Controller:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  isLoading: false,
  search: function(){
    if(this.get('isLoading')) { return }

    this.set('isLoading', true);
    $.ajax({
      context: this,
      success: function(){
        this.set('isLoading', false)
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: I completely agree with you, and I tried that approach, but the disabled attribute doesn't change the button's text to the data-loading-text (which calling the .button('loading') does). The only choice I have would be also change the text like you suggested, which will probably solve it as well, even though in a different way.